# How to smoothly transition between classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How do I make this the transition between classes smooth instead of the shaking effect that you see here:
http://codepen.io/Cogarius/pen/tfhgx

The box shakes severely because of the differences in widths and heights along with changes to the border size which the classes are transitioning.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="original"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.original {
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 150px solid #000000;
  margin: 0px;
}

.changed {
  float: left;
  height: 296px;
  width: 296px;
  border: 2px solid #ff3333;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.original').on('click', function(){  
    $(this).toggleClass( "changed", 500, "easeOutQuad" );
  });
});
```

Comment: At each moment during the change, it is constantly trying to float left. Maybe an absolute position that shifts the center as it changes?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can approach this problem (and the good news is, they are all jitter free :D )

### Box shadow

One trick is to use [box shadows](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) to your advantage. For the rest state, you ensure that the box shadow (inset) fills up the entire dimension of your box. For the toggled state, you collapse the box shadow by reducing its spread radius, and also by changing its colour. [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/bzyLu)

```
.original {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150px #000000;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.changed {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ff3333;
}
```

One caveat: You need to specify the spread radius (fourth number) in pixel values... so if you are using a responsive element, this might be an issue.

Another issue I can foresee is that since the spread radius has to be in pixel values, it might still show jittering as slow transition speeds. For a entirely jitter-free transition, I can only recommend taking advantage of CSS3 2D transforms, which we will need to use pseudo-elements (see next solution).

---

### Pseudo-elements

This trick is to use a pseudo-element, e.g. `::before`, on the container and then scale it when the classes are toggled. Under all states, the container has a black background with a 2px black border. The pseudo-element is absolutely positioned in the center and fills the width and height of its parents, but at rest state it is scaled to 0 (i.e. no size). At the toggled state we de-scale it back to its original dimensions. [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/lCcju)

```
.original {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background:#000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  &::before {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

.changed {
  background-color: #ff3333;
  border-color: #ff3333;
  &::before {
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Note that I have used:

- The `box-sizing` property, so the width declared is the final dimensions
- Transitioning the border colour of the parent, as well as the background colour of the pseudo element.

Comment: Nicely done. Box Shadow is the much cleaner method. +1

Comment: @GaryHayes Definitely. I also prefer the box-shadow method if the OP is going for a simple colour change. However, if a dynamic background is desired (gradients, images and etc), then the more cumbersome but verbose solution using pseudo-elements is desired.

Comment: @GaryHayes Also, the box-shadow method will be prone to jittering too, if the transition duration is too long, because after all, the spread radius is declared as pixel values. The pseudo-element solution uses CSS transforms, which eliminates the issue with subpixel dimensions.

Comment: Please don't decorate links in `<kbd>` tags. This is not what the `<kbd>` element is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your current transition with CSS. Simply add a `transition` property to your `.changed` selector:

```css
.changed {
    ...
    transition: 0.5s; /* Equal to 500ms */
}
```

The shakiness is still there, but it's less prominent than it was when handled through jQuery.

[**CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/okamf).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `width` and `height` values cause this situation. If you want a smooth transition, then you need to use a hardware accelerated css transform, like `scale`, `translateX`, `translateY` etc.

[Here is a more descriptive article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) about that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It is not a critique or request, it actually provides a WAY to the solution. I do not have sufficient reputation to comment, but anyway I would like to help him by giving a quick tip and related article link. So there is no problem if it helps to author.

Comment: @burakcalik Actually no. StackOverflow is not a platform to provide *ways* to a solution. So either way you provide the *result of the way* or this answer will most likely be deleted by mods.